# Why doesn't Colorado legalize other drugs?

Tags: united-states, drugs, colorado

I've heard that Colorado is quite a libertarian state. So why does Colorado legalize only marijuana? Why doesn't it legalize other soft drugs?

I understand that in Colorado more people use (or abuse) marijuana than in other states. Still, now that they see the legalization of marijuana works well for the voters why don't they legalize more?

Have there been any proposals to legalize more? What arguments have opponents of such legalization put forward in Colorado specifically?